# Google visualization drawTable() with var view not working

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Following is my code:

```
<head>
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["table"]});

var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);
var jsonData = ${requestScope.jsonData};

// Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

var addButton = document.getElementById('add');
var removeButton = document.getElementById('remove');

function drawTable() {
  table.draw(view);
}

removeButton.onclick=function(){
    view.hideColumns([1]);
    drawTable();
}

drawTable();

</script>
</head>
```

When I include the following lines inside drawTable() function, it works and leaving them outside (like in my code above) doesn't work.

```
var jsonData = ${requestScope.jsonData};

// Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
```

The reason I would like to leave them outside is because I am trying to access the var view from another function that will hide column of the view on a button click.

Thank you for all your help in advance.

Comment: of course, google api hasn´t loaded yet, so will throw error. You need to put it inside drawTable. If you want to access it outside, just use `var view;` outside, and inside: `view =  new google.visualization.DataView(data);`

Comment: thanks! if you post it as answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

The very purpose of `google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);` is to avoid calling google api´s function before the library has loaded, as it is loaded by async. So whenever you use the api, it should always be inside the `drawTable()` function or somewhere else that runs after that function.

To be able to use the data outside the `drawTable()`, you just need to creat the var outside and then modify it inside:

```
var view = null;
var table = null;

function drawTable(){
    //your code... 
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    //your code... 
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    //your code... 
}
```

And then you can do:

```
removeButton.onclick=function(){
    if(view != null && table != null){
        view.hideColumns([1]);
        table.draw(view);
    }
}
```